# Gstreamer - streaming with TCP sources

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to stream video using TCP. Following is the server pipeline:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=<movie>.mkv ! decodebin ! ffenc_mpeg4 bitrate=5000000 ! rtpmp4vpay mtu=1400 pt=96 ssrc=0 timestamp-offset=0 seqnum-offset=0 send-config=true ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=5000
```

And the client pipeline is:

```
gst-launch tcpclientsrc host=192.168.1.93 port=5000 ! capsfilter caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)2147483647, encoding-name=(string)MP4V-ES, profile-level-id=(string)1, config=(string)000001b001000001b58913000001000000012000c48d88007d0a041e1463000001b24c61766335322e3132332e30, payload=(int)96, ssrc=(uint)298758266, clock-base=(uint)3097828288, seqnum-base=(uint)63478" ! rtpmp4vdepay ! ffdec_mpeg4 ! autovideosink
```

I had to include a capsfilter between tcpclientsrc and rtpmp4vdepay. This does not seem to be required if I use the udpsrc however. (I cant seem to get the multicast based streaming to work through my BT router). When started  the client starts to play the video, but it is garbage and I can see following warning in the client side.

```
WARNING: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpMP4VDepay:rtpmp4vdepay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstbasertpdepayload.c(387): gst_base_rtp_depayload_chain (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpMP4VDepay:rtpmp4vdepay0:
Received invalid RTP payload, dropping
```

This warning is emitted continuously.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Could you try with gstreamer 1.0 and see if it works? gst-launch-1.0 instead of gst-launch and ffenc_mpeg4 would become avenc_mpeg4. The reason is that gstreamer 0.10 is not maintained for 3+ years now.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Infact I started all this with gstreamer 1, but I was not able to find out how to install avenc_mpeg4 in fedora 20. Could I please know the package name?

Comment: Fedora does not release binary packages for libav. Instead, they release packages for ffmpeg. In the other hand, gstreamer1-libav only support libav, not ffmpeg. So I had to manually build libav for fedora 20. However, even after doing that I still get the same error: